# Postfix Summaries?

Tags: postfix

Is there anyway I can get a report directly from Postfix about how many emails were sent per day, or other similar statistics? As a "out of the box" solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mailgraph](http://mailgraph.schweikert.ch/) provides a fairly good overview of the health of your mail system.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your "directly from Postfix" requirement is, but I'll offer [pflogsumm.pl](http://jimsun.linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html) as an option. It just runs via cron and parses through your mail logs, generating aggregate statistics as it goes.

Comment: I suppose I just meant "that wasn't hard to implement". I'll check out that script...

Answer (score 1):

I added some postfix stats to ganglia.  These are not daily stats, but by the minute stats.
Here is my [blog post](http://blog.toppledwagon.com/toppolog/2009/10/how-i-got-postfix-stats-into-ganglia.html) about it.